# Fetching Apple RSS with error HTTP 400 Bad request

Tags: php, rss, file-get-contents

I am trying to fetch Apple RSS feeds using PHP which used to work fine earlier but lately it is showing the error "Error 400 Bad request"

I have tried all possible checks in my code and it is alright. Searching on web doesn't help as there is no related info on this.

My best guess would be that Apple has implemented some kind of security onto their site which is not allowing to download XML's using `file_get_contents()` although I can open the XML in the web browser.

The XML file can be downloaded from http://www.apple.com/rss and there is a link for RSS generator on the right.

Anyone on this?

Comment: It works for me. Can you post your code and the URL that's failing?

Comment: http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=300/genre=6018/xml

Comment: Code is standard PHP to read and save file: `file_get_contents($url);  file_put_contents(/folder_path);` This URL works but not the former one `http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=300/xml`

Comment: Have you tried using Curl? Maybe set a user-agent, so the server will think it's a real user.

Comment: @MathieuImbert Curl works where the direct file_get_contents doesn't. Thanks